# Python decorators: Doubled output

Tags: python, python-decorators

Using Python 3.4.4 on a Windows XP (sp3) machine, the following code, which employs an elementary decorator for educational purposes, displays a doubled output and I am at a loss as to why:

```
def decorated_by(func):
    func.__doc__ += '\nDecorated by decorated_by!!!'
    return func

@decorated_by
def add(x, y):
    '''Return the sum of x and y.'''
    return x + y

add = decorated_by(add)
print (help(add))
```

**Output**:

```
C:\>python test30.py
Return the sum of x and y.
Decorated by decorated_by!!!
Decorated by decorated_by!!!
```

The code is being run from within a file on the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: You are double decorating it, you either need `@deccorate_by` or `add = decorated_by(add)` not  both. The former being syntactic sugar for the later. So you have effectively got `add = decorated_by(decorate_by(add))`

Comment: Thank you. Since I have just begun learning about decorators, your help is greatly appreciated.